# Format cells that do not contain multiple strings

Tags: excel

Bob, John, and Simon are working on a project and tally their expenses in a spreadsheet.

When Bob makes an entry, it must contain (at least) his name (not case sensitive). An entry might look like this:

```
A             B
shoes (bob)   20
```

While Bob and John make some entries, Simon makes the majority of them and doesn't write his name.

I am able to color Bob's and John's entries by using the rule:

```
=SEARCH("bob",$A1)>0
=SEARCH("john",$A1)>0
```

But am having trouble with Simons. How can I search for text NOT containing bob and NOT containing john?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("John",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bob",A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: I think its working, but now only john and bob are being highlighted. What is the NOT operator in excel? <>ISNUMBER(...) is not recognized

Comment: Got it, the operator is actually NOT. Surrounded your formula with NOT does what I want. Now all the rows are colored, even empty ones. Is it possible to surround this whole formula with AND NOT BLANK?